Quarkus - SmallRye Reactive Messaging - Kafka topic prefix
I'm configuring my application to be used on many environments, but I want them to use the same Kafka broker.
To achieve this, I need to prepend the prefix or append the postfix to the topic name, (e.g. qa-some-topic or some-topic-preprod, so that each application stack uses a different topic on the same broker?
Is it possible to automatically prepend the prefix to all - in and out topic names - not only the ones assumed from the channel name, but also specified manually via topic property), as well as delayed-retry-topic and dead-letter-queue topic ?
mp.messaging.outgoing.some-topic-out.topic=some-topic
mp.messaging.incoming.some-topic.delayed-retry-topic.topics=some-topic-retry_100,some-topic-retry_1000,some-topic-retry_15000,some-topic-retry_60000,some-topic-retry_600000
mp.messaging.incoming.some-topic.dead-letter-queue.topic=some-topic-dead-letter


You can configure different topic attributes using Config profiles and Property expressions
For example:
%dev.kafka-topic-prefix=dev-
%qa.kafka-topic-prefix=qa-
%prod.kafka-topic-prefix=prod-
...
mp.messaging.outgoing.some-topic-out.topic=%{kafka-topic-prefix}some-topic
...


To achieve your goal of using the same Kafka broker across multiple environments while having environment-specific topic names, you can leverage environment variables to dynamically prefix or suffix the topic names.
Here's an example of how you can configure your application:

Define an environment variable to hold the desired prefix or suffix for each environment. For example, you could use ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX for prefixes or ENV_TOPIC_SUFFIX for suffixes.
In your application.properties configuration file, use string interpolation to incorporate the environment variable value into the topic names:

# Define the prefix/suffix variable - default set to "prod"
env.topic.prefix=${ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX:prod}

# Main topic
mp.messaging.outgoing.some-topic-out.topic=${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic

# Delayed retry topics
mp.messaging.incoming.some-topic.delayed-retry-topic.topics=\
${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-retry_100,\
${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-retry_1000,\
${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-retry_15000,\
${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-retry_60000,\
${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-retry_600000

# Dead letter queue topic
mp.messaging.incoming.some-topic.dead-letter-queue.topic=${env.topic.prefix}-some-topic-dead-letter


When deploying your application to a specific environment, set the ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX (or ENV_TOPIC_SUFFIX) environment variable to the desired value for that environment.

For example, in a QA environment, you could set ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=qa, which would result in topic names like qa-some-topic, qa-some-topic-retry_100, and qa-some-topic-dead-letter.
In a pre-production environment, you could set ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=preprod, resulting in topic names like preprod-some-topic, preprod-some-topic-retry_100, and preprod-some-topic-dead-letter.
By using environment variables, you can easily configure your application to use different topic name prefixes or suffixes across different environments without modifying the application code or configuration files for each deployment.
This approach allows you to maintain a single Kafka broker while ensuring that each environment uses its own set of topics, preventing conflicts or data leakage between environments.
Setting the Environment Variable
Unix/Linux Environments
To set the ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX environment variable in Unix-like environments (e.g., Linux, macOS), you can use the export command:
export ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=qa

This will set the ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX environment variable to qa for the current shell session. To make the change persistent across sessions, you can add the export command to your shell configuration file (e.g., ~/.bashrc for Bash, ~/.zshrc for Zsh).
Docker
When running your application in a Docker container, you can set the environment variable using the -e or --env flag:
docker run -e ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=qa your-image-name

Alternatively, you can define the environment variable in your Dockerfile:
ENV ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=qa

Windows
In Windows, you can set an environment variable permanently for the current user or system-wide using the Control Panel or the setx command:
setx ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX "qa"

Alternatively, you can set the environment variable temporarily for the current command prompt session using the set command:
set ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX=qa

After setting the ENV_TOPIC_PREFIX environment variable in your desired environment, your application will use the specified prefix (e.g., qa-) when constructing the Kafka topic names.
